Hide elements with jquery
I would like to hide individual element blocks that are identified by id`s.
I have used a jquery function to do this.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=”apple-mobile-web-app-capable” content=”yes “>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>

    function changeMenu(menu){
        $('#Slide_home').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#Slide_sub01').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#Slide_sub02').css({'display':'none'});  
        $('#Slide_'+menu).css({'display':'block'});
        }

    </script>

    <style>
    body { 
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0px; 
        background-color: rgb(53, 61, 64);  
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
        height: 100%; 
        overflow-x: hidden; 
    } 

    #Menu {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        
        }
        
    .ButtonWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    }      
        
    .ButtonWrapper > div {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;  
    }
    </style>
      

</head>


<body>

<div id="Slide_home"> 

home
            
</div>

<div id="Slide_sub01">

01

</div>

<div id="Slide_sub02"> 

02

</div>

<div id="Menu">          
    <div class="ButtonWrapper">
        <div>
            <img class="" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="changeMenu('home');" src="01.png" alt="home"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img class="" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="changeMenu('sub01');" src="02.png" alt="sub_01"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img class="" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="changeMenu('sub02');" src="03.png" alt="sub_02"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                         
</body>
</html>

In principle the function works, when I press a button the corresponding other elements are hidden. But at the beginning all elements are visible. How can I display only the elements for home at the beginning?
Best regards
Jens

Wrap the slides into a div and hide with CSS, add active class to the first slide and display this class as a block:
.slides>* {
    display: none;
}

.slides>*.active {
    display: block;
}

You can add the active class with JS:
  $('.slides >*:first-child, .ButtonWrapper >*:first-child').addClass('active');

Here you can see that we can easily mark active state for the buttons too.
Rewrite your show/hide code so you fully use jQuery event delegation. That way you don't need any element IDs and can add as many slides as you want:


$(() => {

  $('.slides >*:first-child, .ButtonWrapper >*:first-child').addClass('active');

  $('.ButtonWrapper').on('click', 'img', e => {
    const idx = $(e.target).parent().index();
    $('.slides, .ButtonWrapper').children().removeClass('active');
    $(`.slides >*:eq(${idx}), .ButtonWrapper >*:eq(${idx})`).addClass('active');
  });

});
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(53, 61, 64);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

}

.ButtonWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.ButtonWrapper>div {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.ButtonWrapper>div.active{
  background: #555;
}

.slides>* {
    display: none;
}

.slides>*.active {
    display: block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides">

<div class="active"> 

home
            
</div>

<div>

01

</div>

<div> 

02

</div>
</div>

<div id="Menu">          
    <div class="ButtonWrapper">
        <div >
            <img src="01.png" alt="home"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="02.png" alt="sub_01"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="03.png" alt="sub_02"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Thank you for the extended function. I would still like to insert a language change. If I understand it correctly, the s are displayed one after the other, as the order is. I would like to define different s for the different languages.
How can I access these directly via the buttons?

for example
    <div id="DE_01">
        DE_01
    </div>
    
    <div id="EN_01"> 
        EN_01
    </div>


@Jens it will work with any DIVs, regardless of its attributes. it my answer resolved your problem don't forget to accept it (the gray checkbox) thanks

Thank you for your feedback. I did not formulate my query precisely enough. I have integrated buttons for language change in the menu bar and wanted to address defined s. I didn't get any further at this point. Best regards Jens

Add the following statements to your CSS:
#Slide_sub01,#Slide_sub02{
  display:none
}

